# why the flutter page storage get null result of _StorageEntryIdentifier

Tags: flutter

When I try to tracing the page storage source code in `page_storage.dart` function writeState:

```
  void writeState(BuildContext context, dynamic data, { Object? identifier }) {
    _storage ??= <Object, dynamic>{};
    if (identifier != null) {
      _storage![identifier] = data;
    } else {
      final _StorageEntryIdentifier contextIdentifier = _computeIdentifier(context);
      if (contextIdentifier.isNotEmpty) {
        _storage![contextIdentifier] = data;
      }
    }
  }
```

I found the `contextIdentifier` is empty when scroll the component and trigger to set the state value, I have already add the key in the getx component like this:

```
 SingleChildScrollView buildListView(Item item, BuildContext context) {
      return SingleChildScrollView(
          key: PageStorageKey<String>("article-detail-" + item.id),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [])
)}
```

why the `contextIdentifier` was null? Am I missing something? in the outer level of component, I have already added the page storage component like this:

```
      return PageStorage(
          bucket: global.pageStorageBucket,
          child: Scaffold())
```